What is the difference between a push rod and torque tube control system?
What is the difference between a push rod and a torque tube control system for actuating control surfaces on a GA aircraft?
A push rod sounds like it could replace a cable for elevators and rudder when attached to a rudder or elevator tab.
A torque tube sounds like it has a twisting action and sounds like it could replace a bellcrank for flaps or ailerons, but really, I have no idea what the difference is.

It's not clear whether you already know what are the two solutions, and your question is what are the pros and cons of each one? or if you're asking for a description of each solution. If you don't clarify, you may have incomplete answers.

@ mins Asking for the difference between the two systems is not a asking for the pros and cons of each system.

Avoid torque tubes - at the same mass they will be much less stiff, raising the risk of flutter.

@Peter Kämpf Do you mean an embedded tube in a control surface like the tubes in the canard on a Rutan designed Varieze?

@Fred The length is the issue here. Short tubes are OK to transfer torque. If they run the length of the fuselage or wing, make them loaded in tension or compression, not torque.
